# Posting a notification on a friend's wall once

Tags: facebook, fbconnect

I have a website where in users  can join it only through facebook login/connect.

1. I want a one time post to be made on all the user's(new user joining the site through fblogin) friends walls. The post would be some what like "Suresh Adams joined abcd site, and other meta data like image, title and description typically describing the site"
2. if posting on all friends walls is not possible then atleast a post must be done on the user wall.

As said before this is only a one time post made only during the time of new users joining the site through fblogin.

Please let me know how to get this done and what permissions to ask for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to know, any good reason to leave the people that doesn’t use Facebook out?

Comment: _“I want a one time post to be made on all the user's(new user joining the site through fblogin) friends walls.”_ – many of those users receiving such _unwanted_ posts from your app might consider this spam, and therefor report it. So what you are planning is a good way to get your app shut down quite quickly, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't like when you publish in all friends feed. But you want do that :

- asked permission "publish_stream"
- get all friends with FQL 
  --> SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
- post ('me/feed')